# Populate an Array of Objects Using a Database

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create and populate an array of objects with information returned from a database query. I can't seem to get this working properly with my code below.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Module Object:

```
public class Module {
public String moduleEnglishTitle;
public String moduleJapaneseTitle;
public String moduleCompletionRate;
public int moduleRating;
public Module() {
    super();
}

public Module(String moduleEnglishTitle, String moduleJapaneseTitle, String moduleCompletionRate, int moduleRating) {
    super();
    this.moduleEnglishTitle = moduleEnglishTitle;
    this.moduleJapaneseTitle = moduleJapaneseTitle;
    this.moduleCompletionRate = moduleCompletionRate;
    this.moduleRating = moduleRating;
}
```

}

These four variables of the object are to be populated from database, into a Module object array in the activity where the data is to be used. This data is then populated into a ListView using a custom ArrayAdapter. The ArrayAdapter, Listview, and Module object all work well together if I manually create the list using this:

```
Module module_data[] = new Module[] {
            new Module("hello","hello","hello", 3),
            new Module("hello","hello","hello", 2)
    };
```

However, I don't want to populate it this way, I want to use data from a database using this cursor:

```
public Cursor getModuleList() {
    Cursor mCursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT mod, engtitle, japtitle FROM master WHERE type='module'", null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

I have this code so far, but it's not working:

```
    Module module_data[] = new Module[moduleInfo.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    while(moduleInfo.isAfterLast()) {

        module_data[i].moduleJapaneseTitle = moduleInfo.getString(1);
        module_data[i].moduleEnglishTitle = moduleInfo.getString(2);
        module_data[i].moduleCompletionRate = "済み： " + moduleStats.getString(7);
        module_data[i].moduleRating = moduleStats.getInt(4);

        moduleInfo.moveToNext();
        moduleStats.moveToNext();
        i++;
    }
```

.................

```
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jp.atomicideas.ne/jp.atomicideas.ne.Story2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at jp.atomicideas.ne.Story2.onCreate(Story2.java:59)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
06-22 20:42:27.045: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Well there's your problem yo have some weird text in your code, "済み： "...lol first find out what is Null at line 59 in Story2.java.  Then you will be able to track it down better.

Comment: Haha, it's not weird code. It's just Japanese. A silly question, but how can I find out what is Null at line 59?

Comment: Step through it in debug mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it this way:

```
    Module module_data[] = new Module[moduleInfo.getCount()];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<7; i++) {
        module_data[i] = new Module(moduleInfo.getString(1), moduleInfo.getString(2),  "済み： " + moduleStats.getString(7), moduleStats.getInt(4));
        moduleInfo.moveToNext();
        moduleStats.movetoNext();
    }
```

The problem was, that I was incorrectly creating and using the Module objects through its constructor.

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have problem here `while(moduleInfo.isAfterLast())`

Change your code to following snippet.

```
int i = 0;
if (moduleInfo.moveToFirst() && moduleStats.moveToFirst())
{
  do {

    module_data[i].moduleJapaneseTitle = moduleInfo.getString(1);
    module_data[i].moduleEnglishTitle = moduleInfo.getString(2);
    module_data[i].moduleCompletionRate = "済み： " + moduleStats.getString(7);
    module_data[i].moduleRating = moduleStats.getInt(4);

    moduleStats.moveToNext();
    i++;
  } while (moduleInfo.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, unfortunately the activity is still crashing.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 module_data[i] = new Module ();
```

and

"!" is missing..........

```
 while(!moduleInfo.isAfterLast()) {
        module_data[i] = new Module ();//<--------------------------
        module_data[i].moduleJapaneseTitle = moduleInfo.getString(1);
        module_data[i].moduleEnglishTitle = moduleInfo.getString(2);
        module_data[i].moduleCompletionRate = "済み： " + moduleStats.getString(7);
        module_data[i].moduleRating = moduleStats.getInt(4);

        moduleInfo.moveToNext();
        moduleStats.moveToNext();
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. The app is still crashing unfortunately.

Comment: module_data[i] = new Module (); in loop

Comment: Hello, still crashing at this. I've updated above with the log cat output, also this error comes up in the error log:

Current file is not a match for the given config.

Comment: is this file name is Story2.java ?

Comment: Yes, this activity is Story2.java

Comment: Line 59 is this one:
module_data[i] = new Module ();

Answer (score 0):

Add an excalmation mark to `moduleInfo.isAfterLast()`.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't do the trick. The app is still crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I am using an **ArrayList instead...**

`Module mod;`

`ArrayList<Module> module_data = new ArrayList<Module>();`

`final Cursor cursor = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null,null );`

`while(cursor.moveToNext()){`

`mod = new Module();`

`module_data.add(new` `module(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getInt(3));`

`}`